# Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getToken on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_messaging)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, push-notification

I try to get a firebase cloud messaging token to the my flutter app. which is running on the android emulator What went wrong here?. I tried `flutter run` but this is not working, I here I used **1.firebase_messaging: ^6.0.9 as a dependency** and **2.**

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';

class Notifications_ extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Notifications_State createState() => _Notifications_State();
}

class _Notifications_State extends State<Notifications_> {

  final FirebaseMessaging _messaging=FirebaseMessaging();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _messaging.getToken().then((token)
    {
      print(token);
    });

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('notification'),
      ),
      body: Text('body testing'),
    );
  }
}
```

> ```
>  E/flutter ( 5931): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getToken on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_messaging)
> ```
>
> E/flutter ( 5931): #0      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:319:7)
>               E/flutter ( 5931): 
>               E/flutter ( 5931): #1      FirebaseMessaging.getToken (package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart:150:27)
>               E/flutter ( 5931): #2      _Notifications_State.initState (package:sampletestingpro/Notification.dart:17:16)
>               E/flutter ( 5931): #3      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4355:58)
>               E/flutter ( 5931): #4      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
>               E/flutter ( 5931): #5      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3194:14)
>               E/flutter ( 5931): #6      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2988:12)
>               E/flutter ( 5931): #7      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
>               E/flutter ( 5931): #8      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
>               E/flutter ( 5931): #9      StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4298:5)
>               E/flutter ( 5931): #10     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2977:15)
>               E/flutter ( 5931): #11     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
>               E/flutter ( 5931): #12     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
>               E/flutter ( 5931): #13     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4298:5)
>               E/flutter ( 5931): #14     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2977:15)
>               E/flutter ( 5931): #15     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
>               E/flutter ( 5931): #16     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
>               E/flutter ( 5931): #17     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4557:5)
>               E/flutter ( 5931): #18     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2977:15)
>               E/flutter ( 5931): #19     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
>               E/flutter ( 5931): #20     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
>               E/flutter ( 5931): #21     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4557:5)
>               E/flutter ( 5931): #22     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2977:15)
>               E/flutter ( 5931): #23     RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5161:32)
>               E/flutter ( 5931): #24     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5561:17)
>               E/flutter ( 5931): #25     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2977:15)
>               E/flutter ( 5931): #26     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
>               E/flutter ( 5931): #27     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
>               E/flutter ( 5931): #28     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4413:5)
>               E/flutter ( 5931): #29     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2977:15)
>               E/flutter ( 5931): #30     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
>               E/flutter ( 5931): #31     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
>               E/flutter ( 5931): #32     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4557:5)
>               E/flutter ( 5931): #33     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2977:15)
>               E/flutter ( 5931): #34     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
>               E/flutter ( 5931): #35     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
>               E/flutter ( 5931): #36     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4413:5)
>               E/flutter ( 5931): #37     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2977:15)
>               E/flutter ( 5931): #38     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5452:14)
>               E/flutter ( 5931): #39     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2977:15)
>               E/flutter ( 5931): #40     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
>               E/flutter ( 5931): #41     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
>               E/flutter ( 5931): #42     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4298:5)
>               E/flutter ( 5931): #43     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2977:15)
>               E/flutter ( 5931): #44     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5452:14)
>               E/flutter ( 5931): #45     Element.update.

Comment: The plugin would not be loaded via hot reload. You meed to rebuild the project again to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: **Keep the google JSON service file inside the app folder,**]

**Keep the google JSON service file inside the app folder,** I wrongly put the JSON file inside the src/ folder that's why I got an error

Comment: I am having this issue for ios device

Comment: I place my google JSON service file inside the app folder. still getting this issue, do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

So after try many solution this worked for me!

[MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method FcmDartService#initialized on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_messaging_background](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2223#issuecomment-603858526)